# Socket Server - Pass client messages through

Tags: java, sockets

I am creating a chat client. I have multiple clients connecting but I am having a hard time getting them to talk to each other. How do I get the server to send the message incoming from client1 to the rest of the clients without client1 having an echo? I haven't discovered any way to identify each client.

```
public class connect1 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444); 
            while (acceptMore) {
                Socket send1socket = serverSocket.accept();
                new Thread(new sendRunnable(send1socket)).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} //this thread starts my Runnable where I have my PrintWriter
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is have an Array or list of Sockets, and add to it every time a new client connects/subtract when client leaves.

Then when a message is received, loop through that array/list and send message to other clients. (make sure to check the client you are on against the current client in list so you dont send message to the client that sent it to server)

While this is fine on a small scale, it will cause problem on a large scale as you have to loop through a large list each time a new message is received.

to have chatRooms or something, you can have a multidimensional array (`Array[room][socket]`)
then you can do loop through certain rooms and only send to those clients, or loop through all, etc.

To send to specific users only, you can have a User.java class that has a username and a socket in it. then, instead of doing an array of sockets, use an array of users and in your loop, check username and only send to the required users.

Flow:
UserA connects to server, sends username to be `bob`
server recieves connections, makes new `User` object, sets username to bob and sets socket to users socket, then adds that User object to `User[]`

UserB connects to server, sends username `john`
same deal, server makes new user object etc etc.

`john` sends a message to server and tells it to only send the message to `bob`
Server loops through `User[]` and checks username of them, if username matches `bob` server calls `getSocket` on that user object, this returns the socket connection for that user.
server then gets the outputStream of that socket, and creates a printwriter with it. the it sends the message received from `john` through the newly create printwriter.

Comment: How do you tell the server to only send the message to those clients? I don't know what the code is to send to specific ports

Comment: for specific sets of users, you can use a chatroom type thing using an array like I mentioned in my answer, or the client has to send a list of usernames it wants to send the message to, then server side you have a User.java class that contains properties like Socket, and name and whatnot. As you are looping through your `User[]` you only send to those whose username is in the list sent by client

Comment: I understand the process of saving the names and having the server check the names before sending a message but once it comes time to send a message what do in my sendthread? I don't know how to go from checking if a certain person is connected to sending to that specific port.

Comment: well if you want to keep users after the log out, have a field that is just a boolean, set it to true when they are connected and false when they are not. You can even have an `String[]` in there of offline messages, and loop through and send those when they connect again.
And to send a message, get the socket associated with that user and use that outputstream.

Comment: In my thread I have `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(send1socket.getOutputStream(), true);`. I'm not sure if you understand what I am asked or not. I have no idea what to type to send a message to a clients specific port.

Comment: the socket knows the port.
The way a socket works is you are technically always connected to client/server, the server simply writes things to the socket, you don't have to specify what port you want to use.

Comment: You aren't making it clear on how to send a message just to certain people that are connected. All you are telling me is how to store names in an array and nothing about sending.

Comment: Im saying make an array of user objects, not usernames. in the userobjects have a function `getUsername()` that returns the username and a `getSocket` function that returns the socket. 
if you get a message from a client that specifies to send to a specific user, loop through your array of user objects, perform `getUsername` and compare with the required username.
If it matches, use `getSocket` to get the socket connection for that user, and send your message through that socket.

Comment: Updated answer, I don't know how I can make this any clearer.

Answer (score -1):

If your question is how to send/receive messages over a socket, the following is one way to do it.

To send:

```
String message = "..." // message to send
output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
output.writeInt(message.getBytes().length);  // first you send how long the message is
output.write(message.getBytes(), 0, message.getBytes().length);  // then you send the message
```

And to read:

```
DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
if(input.available() > 0) {  // important - makes sure the code doesn't "block" and wait for input
    byte[] bytes = new byte[input.readInt()]; // makes a byte[] of the size of the message it's going to read
    input.read(bytes,0,bytes.length);  // reads the actual message to the byte array
    String message = new String(bytes,0,bytes.length,"UTF-8");  // convert the message back into a String
}
```

You should see [`Socket#getOutputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream%28%29) and [`Socket#getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream%28%29), and then use methods in the [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) and [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) class. input.ava

As for your other question, if you want a client to be able to send messages to specific other client(s), the client must know exactly which client(s) it wants to send the message to. When the client sends a message to the server, that information has to be part of the message. The server would use that to selectively send the message to specific `Sockets`.

There would have to be a system in place of course. For example, for a chat app each client might have a username. You could have a global class `HashSet<User>` variable - where a `User` has a `Socket` and a `String` (username). The client's message to the server could then be a (series of) username(s) followed by the actual message. The server would then iterate through the `HashSet<User>` and send the actual message only to `Users` with matching usernames.

Source: I'm making a chat app right now as well, and this is how I'm doing it. That's not to say there aren't other ways, or even better ways.

Comment: Okay, how would I only send to the specific ports when I send the message in the server?

Comment: What would I type in the send thread to only send the message to the specific ports?

Comment: @Dale Put it in my answer... this is one way to do it. Basically you get a DataOutputStream object from the Socket you want to send to, and write the length of the message and then the actual message to that object. On the other side you'd have get DataInputStream object from the Socket to read from, and then you read first the length of the actual message, and then the actual message. It also avoids blocking on input.